# Re: parsing a svg file using batik svg parser

Tags: java, apache, parsing, svg, batik

I need to know how to parse a svg file using batik svg parser.

Here is my svg file:

```
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <line id="svg_1" y2="395" x2="449" y1="395" x1="449" opacity="0.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
  <path id="svg_2" d="m 200,159 c-3,53 57,-63 57,-63 c 0,0 108,-16 108,-16 c 0,0 73,79 73,79 c 0,0 -32,77 -32,77 c 0,0 -69,74 -69,74 c 0,0 -92,-18 -92,-18 c 0,0 -78,-27 -78,-27 c 0,0 -18,-85 -18,-85 c 0,0 51,-21 51,-21 z" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Now I wanna read ie parse and get only the  tag value.

Comment: You say TAG Value however, there is no tag value.  What value are you trying to parse form the svg? Title?

Comment: wat i meant as tag value is the <path> tag. reading the id,d,stroke-width etc tat is present inside the path tag.

Comment: Just parse it with an XML library in whatever language.  Path would be considered an element, id,d,etc would be considered attributes of that element.  Standard XML libraries have this capability.

Comment: yes i did the same using SAX parser. but i want to know is how to do the same using batik parser.is it possible?